# Setting header on Word 

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2007

I have chapter heading to be listed as “CHAPTER 1 Introduction”. This should come in two lines. However I cannot use enter (because if I use enter, this will be listed as tow items in the index.). So how do I achieve this without using ‘enter’ key? 
The objective is

1. “CHAPTER 1” should come in one line
2. “Introduction” should come in the next line
3. In the Index section, it should be listed only once (in one row)

Comment: I would recommend that you register for Super User, that way you won't lose your temporary account/login...Or email team@stackoverflow.com and have them merge this account with a new one...

Answer (score 1):

You want to insert a "text wrapping break." In Word 2007, you can find the text wrapping break on the "page layout" tab in the "page setup" box under "breaks."

Comment: I think a quicker way of doing this is to use Shift+Enter